# Generating sums, and/or sums of products etc. from the results of itertools groupby aggrigation

Tags: python, group-by, sum, aggregates

It there a builtin (or naive) way for processing (sum, count) the aggregates generated by itertools.groupby?

e.g. Given the table in the example code with a discount of 10%...

I want to:

```
# Select each city...
for city,city_purchases_d in itertools.groupby(transaction_l, 
                                               lambda d: d["city"]):
  print Aggregate( city,sum(|qty|),sum(|qty * price|)*(1-discount) ) *
              city_purchases_d
```

Input Data:

```
discount=0.10 # 10%

transaction_l=(
  dict(trans=201, name="Anne",  city="LAX", item="Apple", qty=10, price=1.33),
  dict(trans=202, name="Betty", city="LAX", item="Banana",qty=20, price=2.33),
  dict(trans=203, name="Carol", city="LAX", item="Cherry",qty=30, price=3.33),
  dict(trans=101, name="Andy",  city="NYC", item="Avodado",qty=1, price=1.32),
  dict(trans=102, name="Andy",  city="NYC", item=u"Açaí",  qty=1, price=1.70),
  dict(trans=103, name="Bob",   city="NYC", item="Bacuri", qty=3, price=2.10),
  dict(trans=104, name="Cliff", city="NYC", item="Carrot", qty=4, price=2.22),
  dict(trans=105, name="David", city="NYC", item="Donut",  qty=5, price=3.00)
)
```

Output would be:

```
('LAX',60,143.82)
('NYC',14,29.88)
```

i.e.

```
In LAX purchased 60 fruit at the total price of $143.82   
In NYC purchased 14 fruit at the total price of $29.88
```

ps. I notice that there are lots of similar questions to this... but none that simply take (something like) a naive expression `city,sum(|qty|),sum(|qty * price|)*(1-discount)` for aggregation.

edit: (at the cost of using generator comprehension) one can almost achieve the effect as follows:

```
discount=0.10 # 10%
desc_f="In %s purchased %s fruit at the total price of $%.2f"
for city,city_purchases_d in itertools.groupby(transaction_l, lambda d: d["city"]):
# alternatively - Plan B: manually creating aggregation DOES also work:
  qty_x_price=list(trans["qty"]*trans["price"] for trans in list(city_purchases_d))
  qty=(trans["qty"] for trans in city_purchases_d)
  print desc_f%(city,sum(qty),sum(qty_x_price)*(1-discount))
```

Comment: What is `discount` here?

Comment: `discount=0.10 # i.e. 10%`

Comment: Why do you want to use `eval`?

Comment: I dont want to use "eval" per-se, rather (I believed) I wanted to use standard python expressions -  for readability of code - but (somehow) with aggregations...  hence my interest in all the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding the following code sample for interest only...

```
def eval_iter(expr_str, global_d, local_d, dict_iter, sep="|"):
  expr_l=expr_str.split(sep)
  if isinstance(dict_iter, dict): dict_iter=dict_iter.itervalues()

  aggregation_l=[]
  for eval_locals in dict_iter:
    locals().update(eval_locals)
    aggregation_l.append(
      eval(",".join(expr_l[1::2]).join("[]"), globals(), locals()))
    for key in eval_locals: del locals()[key] # cleanup a bit

  expr_l[1::2]=["aggregation_l[%d]"%enum for enum in range(len(expr_l)/2)]

  local_d["aggregation_l"]=zip(*aggregation_l)
  return eval("".join(expr_l), global_d, local_d)


discount=0.10 # 10%
desc_f="In %s purchased %s fruit at the total price of $%.2f"

# The QUERY: -------- 8>< - - - - cut here - - - -
for city,city_purchases_d in itertools.groupby(transaction_l, 
                                               lambda d: d["city"]):
  print desc_f%eval_iter("city,sum(|qty|),sum(|qty * price|)*(1-discount)",
                         globals(), locals(), city_purchases_d)
```

Output: as required...

```
In LAX purchased 60 fruit at the total price of $143.82 
In NYC purchased 14 fruit at the total price of $29.88
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you need some flexibility in the aggregate processing of the data, perhaps input by a user? Otherwise it's pretty easy to do this with `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

discount=0.10
transaction_l=(
  dict(trans=201, name="Anne",  city="LAX", item="Apple", qty=10, price=1.33),
  dict(trans=202, name="Betty", city="LAX", item="Banana",qty=20, price=2.33),
  dict(trans=203, name="Carol", city="LAX", item="Cherry",qty=30, price=3.33),
  dict(trans=101, name="Andy",  city="NYC", item="Avodado",qty=1, price=1.32),
  dict(trans=102, name="Andy",  city="NYC", item=u"Açaí",  qty=1, price=1.70),
  dict(trans=103, name="Bob",   city="NYC", item="Bacuri", qty=3, price=2.10),
  dict(trans=104, name="Cliff", city="NYC", item="Carrot", qty=4, price=2.22),
  dict(trans=105, name="David", city="NYC", item="Donut",  qty=5, price=3.00)
)
desc_f = 'In %s purchased %s fruit at the total price of $%.2f'

for city, transactions in groupby(transaction_l, key=lambda d: d['city']):
    transactions = list(transactions)
    print desc_f % (city,
                    sum(t['qty'] for t in transactions),
                    sum( (t['qty']*t['price'])*(1-discount)
                        for t in transactions))
```

**Output**

```
In LAX purchased 60 fruit at the total price of $143.82
In NYC purchased 14 fruit at the total price of $29.88
```

If you need the flexibility of executing arbitrary "queries" on the data, this might be a naive (or even a bizarre) suggestion, but use SQL queries against an in-memory SQLite database?

```
import sqlite3

discount=0.10 # 10%

transaction_l=(
  dict(trans=201, name="Anne",  city="LAX", item="Apple", qty=10, price=1.33),
  dict(trans=202, name="Betty", city="LAX", item="Banana",qty=20, price=2.33),
  dict(trans=203, name="Carol", city="LAX", item="Cherry",qty=30, price=3.33),
  dict(trans=101, name="Andy",  city="NYC", item="Avodado",qty=1, price=1.32),
  dict(trans=102, name="Andy",  city="NYC", item=u"Açaí",  qty=1, price=1.70),
  dict(trans=103, name="Bob",   city="NYC", item="Bacuri", qty=3, price=2.10),
  dict(trans=104, name="Cliff", city="NYC", item="Carrot", qty=4, price=2.22),
  dict(trans=105, name="David", city="NYC", item="Donut",  qty=5, price=3.00)
)

memdb = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cursor = memdb.cursor()
# create an in-memory table
r = cursor.execute('create table transactions (trans int, name varchar(30), city char(3), item varchar(20), qty int, price numeric)')
result = cursor.executemany('insert into transactions (trans, name, city, item, qty, price) values (:trans, :name, :city, :item, :qty, :price)', transaction_l)
assert result.rowcount == len(transaction_l)

result = cursor.execute('select city, sum(qty), sum(qty*price)*(1-{}) from transactions group by city'.format(discount))

desc_f = 'In {} purchased {} fruit at the total price of ${:.2f}'
for row in result:
    print desc_f.format(*row)

memdb.close()
```

**Output**

```
In LAX purchased 60 fruit at the total price of $143.82
In NYC purchased 14 fruit at the total price of $29.88
```

So, now your task is to create an SQL query like this:

```
select city, sum(qty), sum(qty*price)*(1-0.1) from transactions group by city
```

from this:

```
city,sum(|qty|),sum(|qty * price|)*(1-discount)
```

which seems pretty doable.

Comment: I like the sqlite magic... parsing sql expressions and mixing sql expressions with python expression is the norm now-days.  Would be nice if I only needed python expressions/code.  However sqllite IS everywhere...

Comment: You don't clearly state your use case so it's difficult to say. Are you trying to execute user entered "queries", or otherwise evaluate a user entered value? Using `eval` is not a safe way to proceed - you might as well use SQL. It might be overkill, but you could consider adding an ORM (e.g. SQLAlchemy) on top - then you don't need to generate the SQL queries but you'll need a domain-specific-language. Even if you use pandas (which, even though SQLite is in the Python standard lib, is probably better than using SQLite), you will need a domain-specific-language.

Comment: The bigger picture (for me in this case): The "queries" are just more code in the same program... except some aggregation needs to be done in the code.  In a "perfect-world" the "query" is readable by the (past/present/future) python coder... The specific code that triggered the question was a time sheet program calculating hour total from a dicts stored in a large "shelve" ... https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html

Comment: Given that Python code  is inherently understandable to the vast majority of Python programmers :), 3 lines of code leveraging a standard library function seems better than 15 lines of specialised code to parse and evaluate what is essentially a domain-specific-language that resembles SQL. Pandas too can be understood by most Python programmers. Or just use SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The desired result can be archived in a simpler way with the Pandas module,

```
import pandas as pd

discount = 0.2

df = pd.DataFrame(list(transaction_l))
df['total_price'] = df.qty*df.price*(1-discount)
res = df.groupby('city').sum()[['qty', 'total_price']]
print(res)
#       qty  total_price
#city 
#LAX    60       127.84
#NYC    14        26.56
```

Comment: I was thinking (having googled) that pandas was the defacto way of doing this... using dataframes kind of seems logical... so I will read up a little about pandas...

Comment: Your totals differ from mine... `('LAX',60,143.82), ('NYC',14,29.88)` (hoping that I got my example right)

Comment: Just thinking aloud, but using dataframes would have the advantage that member functions (such as .groupby and .sum), together with "DF" implemented operators "*" etc could (maybe) introduce a more structured code and better semantic checking?

Comment: The totals differ because this answer uses a 20% discount, not the 10% as per your question. The results shown in this answer are correct for the discount value used.